# Existence of global vector fields on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

According to my book, if $M$ is a smooth manifold the global smooth vector fields form an infinite-dimensional Lie algebra.

However, how do we know of the existence of even one vector field and then how do we know the number of them is infinite?

Comment: Well, the constant zero is a smooth vector field. Also, you can always define nontrivial vector fields, compactly supported within a chart.

Comment: But then it will not be necessarily global. @Berci

Comment: @User12239 it will be global, the vector field is 0 outside the chart. Or maybe you want a vector field with no zero on $M$?

Comment: Yes I didn’t read Berci’s comment well, thanks @AdamChalumeau